# How to fit content which width is for example 900px to the mobile screen to be in original width

Tags: css, reactjs

[image]

I know that this is going to be scaled and small but I i tried with meta tags with different variations but nothing really worked as excpected.

This is also in React.js.

Comment: Without any minimal reproduction, it's hard to give the best answer. But `img{max-width:100vw;}` in your css would fix it

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work as expected? Can you be more specific? For example, when trying to see a website on mobile, the proportions should be different. Font size should be bigger, content arranged in column format, menus collapsed, etc. All these need to be manually programmed to achieve the result (responsive design).

Comment: @PaulPacurar In this case I have to display the full original 900px width on a smaller screen to somehow scale it, and I know what responsive design is but this is a case  I have to avoid using Flexbox or grid I just need the original 900px to be somehow scaled in mobile device it will be probably smaller content but that is fine.

Comment: So what is going wrong when you use scale? Please show what you have tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

@media(max-width=390px){
you use a media query
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).